# spring's ETag filter is not effective when I use async servlet (spring 3.2)

Tags: java, spring, servlet-3.0, etag

Recently we use async feature in servlet 3.0 with spring 3.2, but then our ShallowEtagHeaderFilter was not effective at all, I think it must be the framework flush the response before my content was processed ... 
How to solve it? Anyone has experience?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the code snippets of ShallowEtagFilter in Spring 4.3.5,

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletResponse responseToUse = response;
    if (!isAsyncDispatch(request) && !(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
        responseToUse = new HttpStreamingAwareContentCachingResponseWrapper(response, request);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, responseToUse);

    if (!isAsyncStarted(request) && !isContentCachingDisabled(request)) {
        updateResponse(request, responseToUse);
    }
}

/**
     * Whether request processing is in asynchronous mode meaning that the
     * response will not be committed after the current thread is exited.
     * @param request the current request
     * @since 3.2
     * @see WebAsyncManager#isConcurrentHandlingStarted()
     */
    protected boolean isAsyncStarted(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(request).isConcurrentHandlingStarted();
    }
```

When you use async servlet, the condition would not be met which means the business logic of generating etag would not be invoked.